# Vector Identity

Tags: vector-analysis

So I have a unit vector n. In a formula in a paper I'm reading. I see that $$n\cdot \triangledown n= n \times \triangledown \times n$$ I know that for the topic I'm studying that the orientation of $n$ is not and issue so $n = -n$ which might be helpful...I tried to use the vector triple product on the RHS but ended up at a dead end. I also tried expanding both sides to see if something canceled but to no avail. I'm beggining to think that there may be a typo in the paper... Can it be done? Is there a trick?

Comment: Something's fishy. 

$\mathbf{n} \cdot \triangledown \mathbf{n}$ is a scalar, but $\mathbf{n} \times \triangledown \times \mathbf{n}$ is a vector.

Comment: I also read this as "scalar = vector". Can you cite or post a link to the paper?

Comment: Shouldn't it be as $n(\triangledown \cdot n)$?

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/253894173_Introduction_to_liquid_crystals

Comment: Page 32 equation (34) then becomes the term with the k33 coeff. in eqn (35)

Answer (score 2):

I see two main issues. One is that the paper cited is not very polished; this is likely because it appears set of unpublished notes (which can be found on the author's academic website [here](http://www2.mpip-mainz.mpg.de/~andrienk/teaching/IMPRS/)). In particular, consider the following statement near the start of section 3.2:

> "We consider a uniaxial liquid crystal and let $\mathbf{n}(\mathbf{r})$ be a unit vector giving the direction of the preferred orientation at the point $\mathbf{r}$. As we discussed before, the sign of this vector has no physical significance. Once $\mathbf{n}$ is defined at some point we assume that it varies slowly from point to point. At $\mathbf{r}$ we introduce
>   a local right-handed Cartesian coordinate system $x, y, z$ with $z$ *parallel* to $\mathbf{n}$." [emphasis added]

They then proceed to define the curvature components as partial derivatives of $n_x,n_y$. But if $\mathbf{n}$ and $z$ are parallel, I'd expect these two components to vanish identically. I had initially thought that it should instead be $z$ *perpendicular* to $\mathbf{n}$, but their meaning seems instead to be that $n_z\approx 1$ everywhere near the origin (eq. 22). So you may be well-advised to compare with a separate reference.

The other issue is that, in the question as written, the relevant claim is presented as the vector equality $(\mathbf{n}\cdot\nabla)\mathbf{n}=\mathbf{n}\times \nabla\times \mathbf{n}$. But what appears in the free energy is not these vectors but their squares i.e. their magnitudes, and these being equal is a weaker claim (e.g. $\hat{x}\neq \hat{y}$ but both are unit vectors). So the claim as stated in the question could be false without contradicting the notes. But I haven't confirmed that this is indeed the case.